spring security 6.2.3 error Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'http://localhost:5123' has been blocked by CORS policy
I know there are many posts about this, but they all seem to be broken or old, in fact none of them fit spring security 6.2.3, spring-boot 3.2.4
I've tried various options to allow my frontend to communicate with an endpoint in spring while avoiding the cors problem. Here I bring you one of the solutions I tried but still didn't work. The endpoint is /api/v1/test
A security configuration class:
 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:5123"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","DELETE","OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(
                                AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/api/v1/test")
                        )
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**")
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    } }

A trivial endpoint to test:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/")
@Slf4j
public class TestController {



    @GetMapping(value = "test", produces = "application/json")
    @Operation(method = "GET")
    public ResponseEntity<Test> getTest() {
       ...

Why do I keep getting this error from my Angular frontend?

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://servername/api/v1/test' from
origin 'http://localhost:5123' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource.


because you did not read the docs and define it as it is stated in the docs.... https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html its as simple as that so remove @CrossOrigin remove .cors(c -> c.configurationSource(customCorsConfiguration)) remove your entire CustomCorsConfiguration read the docs

Thanks for your intervention. But as I specified above, I tried various options, first the one you kindly showed, and it was precisely the failure of this one that led me to see other posts. by trying again I confirm that your proposal has not changed anything.

By writing that without updating your post with what you have exactly done and helping us reading this to reproduce your problem, you are claiming that the docs are wrong and that the spring team has a major bug in their software. Either that or that you have written a bad implementation and/or you are not very good at following documentation. But that is impossible for us to say since you have once again not updated your question with enough code for us to reproduce your problem.

I just sat down and implemented CORS in spring security, it took me 10 minutes and it all works flawlessly. If you belive this is a major bug i suggest you file an issue on github to the spring team telling them that their software is faulty. Or you produce a small (with emphasis on small) project that we can run, and correct because us telling you what is wrong and you just writing "no that didnt work" is not productive. Good luck with your problem, have a nice day.

Voted to close as a solution was given, and not enough code was provided to reproduce the problems claimed.

Thanks for your information. I am absolutely not saying that there is a bug in spring, on the contrary... it could be that, since it is a larger project, I have not been good at introducing more useful details for understanding the problem. Or in any case there may be something that I'm missing, always my fault. In any case, I apologize if I'm wasting your time.

.cors(cors -> cors.disable()) will only disable cors filter of the spring security BUT it has not influence on the browser. All modern browsers enforce CORS, independent of which backend you use. Your browser won't let you read the response from backend (even if backend responds with 200) unless there is a response header present that says that your domain is allowed (Access-Control-Allow-Origin). See my answer here on how to set up CORS

Thanks @asgarov1, finally with your approch I find the solution!
